# extract key from dictionary when I search for any specific value from list of values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

> Here is the small sample code what i want
>   Can anyone help to get the key "games" when i get the value of my list > >"league" from user

```
dic = {
    "animal" : ["dog", "cat", "horse"],
    `get games when enters league`
    "games" : ["league", "cs-go", "pubg"] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the dictionary:

```
dic = {
    "animal" : ["dog", "cat", "horse"],
    "games" : ["league", "cs-go", "pubg"] 
}

def get_key(s):
    for k, v in dic.items():
        if s in v:
            return k
```